# Migration to .NET 6 and WCF

Tags: .net, wcf, protobuf-net, circular-reference

We are migrating our software from .NET Framework 4.5.2 to .NET 6.

As you can imagine, that’s a lot of work to do.

So far, our biggest challenge is the loss of WCF that we try to replace with Protobuf-net.

First of all, is that a good idea in your opinion? Seems like everything is more complicated and our software is pretty huge so we want to be sure that’s a good idea.

If that’s the thing to do, we have an issue with circular reference because our data is coming for Entity Framework and we have a lot of loop.

We tried to intercept content in OnSerializing and remove loop but because de message size change, we have an exception.

Do you guys have any tips about this ?

Thank you !

Comment: Getting off "WS-DeathStar" (the underlying standards which WCF sort of implements) to something contemporary is definitely a good idea. Only continue with WS-* if you have to maintain compatibility. The WS-* standards seemed like a good idea, but added so much complexity that they added problems (eg. stands that opened the systems to DDOS - with distributed transactions)